# ¿cómo subir archivos desde mi web a la nube?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive, fileupload

tengo un "sistema" que permite subir y descargar archivos en el propio servidor ¿inconvenientes? que no se puede editar en el navegador, únicamente aquellos archivos que son del tipo "Imagen" permiso visualizarlos, y los que no, simplemente cuando intentan visualizarlo fuerzo la descarga, es algo totalmente obsoleto.

Quiero que mi "sistema" permita subir, editar, imprimir y descargar archivos; por lo tanto pensé en implementar la API de Google Drive, no sé como funciona, ayer perdí todo el día y no pude hacerlo funcionar.

A mi me gustaría lo siguiente: que google drive me proporcione un código javascript que yo ponga en formulario de subida de archivos y que automáticamente lo suba a la cuenta propia del sistema y que me retorne la URL para que yo pueda almacenarla en BD. Posteriormente cuando alguien quiera visualizar, editar, imprimir o descargar ese archivo yo simplemente con la URL delego todo ese trabajo a la API.

Copié un código de internet y me solicitó iniciar sesión, la verdad estoy super confuso de como hacerlo funcionar. Para aclarar, yo no quiero que los archivos se suban a las cuentas personales de los usuarios, quiero que se suban automáticamente a una cuenta que voy a crear sólo y exclusivamente para ser usada en el servidor.

¿Podrían por favor ayudarme? Uso PHP

[Onedrive SDK](https://github.com/krizalys/onedrive-php-sdk)

Comment: Carlos, yo te ayudo pero necesito que describas con exactitud qué es lo que ya intentaste.

Comment: Intenté con la API de onedrive y drive, pero la verdad no lo entiendo. Te agradecería si me ayudas

Comment: Carlos, cuando me refiero a que describas con exactitud qué es lo que ya intentaste me refiero a que por favor postees el código que has usado, las referencia que has leído y los resultados que has obtenido. De esa forma yo sabré como poder ayudarte.

Comment: No tengo código, solo descargué el API de onedrive para php, cambié la secret key y client id, hice pruebas y no me funcionaba, porqué no sé hacerlo funcionar, no hay mucho mas que explicar. Acabo de ponerte el enlace en la pregunta.

Comment: Entiendo. Básicamente buscas un ejemplo, o mejor dicho, un tutorial que te enseñe a trabajar con la API. Voy a ver si puedo trabajar en un ejemplo de Google Drive, pero ten en mente que el propósito de esta comunidad es ayudar a resolver problemas con base a prueba y error de código. No lo tomes a mal porfavor, pero realmente no estamos para hacer el trabajo de los demás.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referencia de Google Drive API: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk
Referencia de como usar la librería de PHP: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started

**Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de un gestor de archivos usando Google Drive**

**Requisitos:** 
 1. Un servidor local para operar con PHP y MySQL (WAMP, MAMP, Etc) 
 2. Una cuenta de google 
 3. Un navegador (Google chrome de preferencia)

**Paso #1 (Preparando el directorio y la librería)** 
 1. Creemos un directorio raíz y elijamos el nombre que más nos guste. 
 2. [Descargamos](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases) a este directorio la librería de APIs de Google y la descomprimimos.
 3. Creemos otra carpeta donde vamos a tener nuestros archivos con código, y a ésta la nombramos "**gestor**". De modo que tiene que mirarse similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Paso #2 (Preparando los archivos de código)** 
 1. Dentro del directorio "gestor", creamos los siguientes archivos:

- acceso.php
- autenticar.php
- descargar.php
- gestor.html
- index.php
- listar.php
- script.js
- subir.php

De modo que la lista de archivos se tiene que ver similar a esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Paso #3 (Llenando los archivos de código su código respectivo)** 
1. Dentro del archivo **acceso.php**, ponemos el siguiente código:

```
<?php

session_start();

//incluir la liberería de php de Google API
require_once '../google-api-php-client-2.1.3/vendor/autoload.php';

//deifnir los permisos requeridos
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

//crear el objeto cliente
$cliente = new Google_Client(); 
$cliente->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/gestor/acceso.php');
$cliente->setAuthConfig("client_secret.json");
$cliente->addScope($scopes);
$cliente->setAccessType('offline');

if (isset($_SESSION['token_de_acceso']) && $_SESSION['token_de_acceso']) {  

  $servidor = "localhost";
  $usuario = "root";
  $contraseña = "";

  //crear conexión
  $con = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña);

  //revisar la conexión
  if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Fallo en la conexión: " . $con->connect_error);
  } 

  //crear base de datos si no existe
  $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS gestor";
  if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "Base de datos creada con éxito<br><br>";
  } else {
      echo "Fallo creando base de datos: " . $con->error . "<br><br>";
  }

  mysqli_select_db($con,"gestor");

  //crear tabla en la base de datos si no existe
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS token (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, token_de_acceso VARCHAR(2000))";
  if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "Tabla creada con éxito<br><br>";
  } else {
      echo "Fallo creando la tabla: " . $con->error . "<br><br>";
  }

  //guardar el token de acceso en forma de un JSON string
  $token_de_acceso = json_encode($_SESSION['token_de_acceso']);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO token (token_de_acceso) VALUES ('$token_de_acceso')";
  if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Token guardado con éxito<br><br>";
  } else {
      echo "Error guardado token: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error . "<br><br>";
  }

  $con->close();
  header("Location: index.php");

} else {

  if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {

    $url_de_auth = $cliente->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($url_de_auth, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

  } else {

    $cliente->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token_de_acceso'] = $cliente->getAccessToken();
    $uri_de_redireccion = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/gestor/acceso.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($uri_de_redireccion, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

  }

}
```

2. Dentro del archivo **autenticar.php** ponemos el siguiente código:

```
<?php session_start(); 

function inicarCliente(){

    //incluir la liberería de php de Google API
    require_once "../google-api-php-client-2.1.3/vendor/autoload.php"; 

    //definir los permisos necesarios 
    $scopes = array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");

    //crear el objeto de cliente de Google
    $cliente = new Google_Client(); 
    $cliente->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/gestor/acceso.php');
    $cliente->setAuthConfig("client_secret.json");
    $cliente->addScope($scopes);
    $cliente->setAccessType('offline');

    return $cliente;

}

function refrescarToken($cliente, $tokenDeAccesso){

    $tokenExpirado = $cliente->isAccessTokenExpired();
    if($tokenExpirado){
        $cliente->refreshToken($tokenDeAccesso["refresh_token"]);
    }

    $_SESSION["token_de_acceso"] = $cliente->getAccessToken(); 
}

?>
```

3. Dentro del archivo **descargar.php** ponemos el siguiente código:

```
<?php

include "autenticar.php";

$idDeDoc = $_POST["idDeDoc"];
$tituloDeDoc = $_POST["tituloDeDoc"];
$tipoDeDoc = $_POST["tipoDeDoc"];

function descargarArchivo($idDeDoc, $tipoDeDoc, $tituloDeDoc){

    $tokenDeAccesso = $_SESSION["token_de_acceso"];

    $cliente = inicarCliente();
    refrescarToken($cliente, $tokenDeAccesso);

    $tokenDeAccesso = $_SESSION['token_de_acceso'];

    $cliente->setAccessToken($tokenDeAccesso);
    $servicio = new Google_Service_Drive($cliente);

    if($tipoDeDoc == "application/vnd.google-apps.document") {

        $ext = ".docx";
        $format = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        $googleDoc = true;

    } else if($tipoDeDoc == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){

        $ext = ".xlsx";
        $format = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        $googleDoc = true;

    } else if($tipoDeDoc == "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"){

        $ext = ".pptx";
        $format = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
        $googleDoc = true;

    } else {

        $ext = ".".explode("/", $tipoDeDoc)[1];
        $googleDoc = false;

    }

    if($googleDoc){
        $archivo = $servicio->files->export($idDeDoc, $format, array('alt' => 'media'));
    } else {
        $archivo = $servicio->files->get($idDeDoc, array('alt' => 'media'));
    }

    $exportacion = fopen($tituloDeDoc.$ext, "w+");
    fwrite($exportacion, $archivo->getBody());
    fclose($exportacion);

    return dirname($tituloDeDoc.$ext)."/".$tituloDeDoc.$ext;
}

echo descargarArchivo($idDeDoc, $tipoDeDoc, $tituloDeDoc);

?>
```

4. Dentro del archivo **gestor.html** ponemos el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gestor Drive</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        body{
            text-align: center;
        }

        .listaArchivos {
            margin: 15px 0px;
            width: 320px;
            height: 25px;
        }

        #descargar{
            margin: 7px 0px;
        }

        #editarArchvio{
            width: 950px;
            height: 630px;
        }

        #circuloEspera,
        #circuloEsperaDos {
            display: none;
            height: 36px;
            width: 36px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #subirArchivo {
            margin: 35px 0px;
        }

        #popup {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: none;
        }

        #contenido-popup {
            background-color: white;
            width: 450px;
            height: 240px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            transform: translateY(100%);
            position: relative;
        }

        .btn {
            padding: 6px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            background-color: whitesmoke;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px gray;
        }

        #nombreDeArchivo{
            height: 20px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Gestor de Archivos Google Drive</h1>

    <div class="menu">

        <select class="listaArchivos" id="listaDeArchivos" disabled>
            <option>Seleccionar archivo...</option>         
        </select>

        <br>

        <button id="descargar" disabled>Descargar</button>
        <img id="circuloEspera" src="https://s5.postimg.cc/r3dog8vg7/loading.gif">

    </div>

    <div class="marco">

        <iframe src="" id="editarArchvio" frameborder="1"></iframe>

    </div>

    <button id="subirArchivo">Subir Archivo</button>

    <div id="popup">
        <div id="contenido-popup">
            <br>
            <h3>SUBIR NUEVO ARCHIVO</h3>
            <br>
            <label for="nuevoArchivoInput" class="btn">Seleccionar Archivo</label><br>
            <input type="file" name="archivo" id="nuevoArchivoInput" style="visibility:hidden;"><br>
            <div id="nombreDeArchivo"></div><img id="circuloEsperaDos" src="https://s5.postimg.cc/r3dog8vg7/loading.gif"><br><br>
            <button id="nuevoArchivo">Subir Nuevo Archivo</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

5. Dentro del archivo **index.php** ponemos el siguiente código:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $contraseña = "";
    $baseDeDatos = "gestor";

    //crear conexión
    $con = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña, $baseDeDatos);

    //revisar la conexión
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        if($con->connect_error == "Unknown database 'gestor'") {
            header("Location: acceso.php");
        } 
        die("Fallo en la conexión: " . $con->connect_error);
    } 

    //obtener token de accesso
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM token";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // obtener datos de cada fila
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $token = $row["token_de_acceso"];
            break;
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 resultados";
        header("Location: acceso.php");
    }

    //cerrar conexión
    $con->close();

    //guardar el token de acceso en la sesión y redirigir a gestor.html
    $_SESSION["token_de_acceso"] = json_decode($token, true);
    header("Location: gestor.html");

?>
```

6. Dentro del archivo **listar.php** ponemos el siguiente código:

```
<?php

include "autenticar.php";

function obtenerListaDeArchivos(){

    $tokenDeAccesso = $_SESSION["token_de_acceso"];

    $cliente = inicarCliente();
    refrescarToken($cliente, $tokenDeAccesso);

    $tokenDeAccesso = $_SESSION['token_de_acceso'];

    $opcionesDeHtml = "<option value=''>Seleccionar archivo...</option>";

    $cliente->setAccessToken($tokenDeAccesso);
    $servicio = new Google_Service_Drive($cliente);

    $tokenDePagina = null;
    $paramsOpcionales = array(
        "pageSize" => 100,
        "pageToken" => $tokenDePagina,
        "q" => "'Id de folder aqui' in parents and trashed != true" // normalmente es algo como 1HeqmJX-1Lsy89CXljmUY-BjubbjfkpsSm
    );

    try {

        do {

            $optParams["pageToken"] = $tokenDePagina;
            $archivos = $servicio->files->listFiles($paramsOpcionales);
            $tokenDePagina = $archivos->nextPageToken;

            foreach ($archivos as $archivo ) {
                $opcionesDeHtml .= "<option value='".$archivo->id.",".$archivo->mimeType."'>".$archivo->name."</option>";
            }

        } while($tokenDePagina);

    } catch(Exception $e) {

        $msjDeError = $e->getMessage();

        if(strpos($msjDeError, "Internal Error") !== false) {
            sleep(2);
            $archivos = $servicio->files->listFiles($paramsOpcionales);
            $tokenDePagina = $driveFiles->nextPageToken;
            foreach ($drivefiles as $file ) {
                $opcionesDeHtml .= "<option value='".$archivo->id."'>".$archivo->name."</option>";
            }
        } else {
            print $msjDeError;
        }
    }

    return $opcionesDeHtml;

}

echo obtenerListaDeArchivos();

?>
```

**OJO** con este archivo. Favor de reemplazar "**Id de folder aqui**" con la Id del folder de google drive donde se van a guardar los archivos.

7. Dentro del archivo **scripts.js** ponemos el siguiente código:

```
function listarArchivos(){

  var solicitud = new XMLHttpRequest();
  solicitud.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("listaDeArchivos").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        document.getElementById("listaDeArchivos").disabled = false;
    }
  };
  solicitud.open("GET", "listar.php", true);
  solicitud.send();

}

function editarArchivo(){

    var elDoc = document.getElementById("listaDeArchivos").value;
    var idDeDoc = elDoc.split(",")[0];
    var tipoDeDoc = elDoc.split(",")[1];
    if(idDeDoc){
        document.getElementById("descargar").disabled = false;
    } else{
        document.getElementById("descargar").disabled = true;
    }

    var altura = (window.innerHeight / 3);
    altura = altura * 2;

    var url;
    if(tipoDeDoc === "application/vnd.google-apps.document"){

        url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/"+idDeDoc+"?rm=demo";

    } else if(tipoDeDoc === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){

        url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+idDeDoc+"?rm=demo";

    } else if(tipoDeDoc === "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"){

        url = "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/"+idDeDoc+"?rm=demo";

    } else {

        url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/"+idDeDoc+"/preview";

    }
    document.getElementById("editarArchvio").setAttribute("src", url);  
}

function descargarArchivo(){

    document.getElementById("descargar").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("circuloEspera").style.display = "initial";

    var elDoc = document.getElementById("listaDeArchivos").value;
    var idDeDoc = elDoc.split(",")[0];
    var tipoDeDoc = elDoc.split(",")[1];
    var tituloDeDoc = document.getElementById("listaDeArchivos").options[document.getElementById("listaDeArchivos").selectedIndex].text;

    var solicitud = new XMLHttpRequest();   
    solicitud.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            console.log(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("descargar").style.display = "initial";
            document.getElementById("circuloEspera").style.display = "none";

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = this.responseText;
            a.download = (this.responseText).substr(2);
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
    };
    solicitud.open("POST", "descargar.php", true);
    solicitud.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    solicitud.send("idDeDoc="+idDeDoc+"&tipoDeDoc="+tipoDeDoc+"&tituloDeDoc="+tituloDeDoc);

}

function subirArchivo(){

    document.getElementById("nombreDeArchivo").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("circuloEsperaDos").style.display = "block";

    var elDoc = document.getElementById("nuevoArchivoInput");
    var path = elDoc.value.split("\\"); 
    var tituloDeDoc = path[path.length -1];

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("archivoParaSubir", elDoc.files[0]);
    formData.append("tituloDeDoc", tituloDeDoc);

    var solicitud = new XMLHttpRequest();   
    solicitud.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            console.log(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("nombreDeArchivo").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("nombreDeArchivo").innerHTML = "Archvio subido";
            document.getElementById("circuloEsperaDos").style.display = "none";
            listarArchivos();
        }
    };
    solicitud.open("POST", "subir.php", true);
    solicitud.send(formData);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    listarArchivos();

    document.getElementById("listaDeArchivos").addEventListener("change", function(){
        editarArchivo();
    });

    document.getElementById("descargar").addEventListener("click", function(){
        descargarArchivo();
    });

    document.getElementById("subirArchivo").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    });

    document.getElementById("popup").addEventListener("click", function(e){
        if(e.target === document.getElementById("popup")){
            document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
        }       
    });

    document.getElementById("nuevoArchivoInput").addEventListener("change", function(){
        var path = (this.value).split("\\");
        document.getElementById("nombreDeArchivo").innerHTML = path[path.length - 1];
    });

    document.getElementById("nuevoArchivo").addEventListener("click", function(){
        subirArchivo();
    });

});
```

8. Dentro del archivo **subir.php** ponemos el siguiente código:

```
<?php

include "autenticar.php";

$archivoParaSubir = $_FILES["archivoParaSubir"];
$tituloDeDoc = $_POST["tituloDeDoc"];
$tituloDeDocPartes = explode(".", $tituloDeDoc);
array_pop($tituloDeDocPartes);
$tituloDeDoc = implode(".", $tituloDeDocPartes);


function subirArchivo($archivoParaSubir, $tituloDeDoc){

    $tokenDeAccesso = $_SESSION["token_de_acceso"];

    $cliente = inicarCliente();
    refrescarToken($cliente, $tokenDeAccesso);

    $tokenDeAccesso = $_SESSION['token_de_acceso'];

    $cliente->setAccessToken($tokenDeAccesso);
    $servicio = new Google_Service_Drive($cliente);

    $info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $tipoDeDoc = $info->file($archivoParaSubir["tmp_name"]);
    $mimeType = explode(";", $tipoDeDoc)[0];

    $metaDatos = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array('name' => $tituloDeDoc, "parents" => ["Id del folder de drive"])); // normalmente es algo así 1HeqmBX-1Lsy8dMAjmUY-Bjufvfsadf
    switch ($mimeType) {

        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document":
        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template":     
        case "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12":
        case "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12":
        case "application/msword":
            $metaDatos->setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");
            break;

        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template":
        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet":   
        case "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12":   
        case "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12":
        case "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12":
        case "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12":
        case "application/vnd.ms-excel":
            $metaDatos->setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
            break;  

        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation":
        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow":  
        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template":   
        case "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12":
        case "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12":
        case "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12":
        case "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12":
        case "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint":
            $metaDatos->setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.presentation");
            break;  

        default:
            break;
    }

    $contenido = file_get_contents($archivoParaSubir["tmp_name"]);
    $archivo = $servicio->files->create($metaDatos, array(
        "data" => $contenido,
        "mimeType" => $mimeType,
        "uploadType" => "multipart",
        "fields" => "id")
    );

    $permiso = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
        'type' => 'anyone',
        'role' => 'writer',
    ));
    $compartir = $servicio->permissions->create(
        $archivo->id, $permiso, array('fields' => 'id'));

    return $archivo->id;
}

echo subirArchivo($archivoParaSubir, $tituloDeDoc);

?><br>
```

**Ojo** con este archivo, pues hay que reemplazar "Id del folder" con la id del folder donde vas a subir los archivos.

**Paso #4 (Habilitando la API dentro de un proyecto y obtener el client secret)** 
1. Ir a la [Consola de APIs](https://console.developers.google.com) y si no hemos creado un proyecto, crear uno.
2. Luego de crear el proyecto, habilitamos la API de Google Drive de la siguiente manera:

- Abrimos el menú de la consola de desarrolladores y seleccionamos la opciones que nos detalla la imagen:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Luego buscamos la API de Google drive y damos click: 
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Después procedemos a habilitar la API dando click en el botón azul.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- A continuación, procedemos a ir a la sección de credenciales. Damos click en el menú y seleccionamos la opción detallada en la imagen:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Después, establecemos el nombre de la app tal y como lo detalla la imagen:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Ahora pasamos a la siguiente opción y seleccionamos el tipo de credencial que queremos crear, tal y como lo indica la imagen:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  - Luego de seleccionar el tipo de credencial, escogemos para qué tipo de aplicación la vamos a usar. Seleccionamos la opción que nos indica la imagen y escribimos el valor que nos indica la imagen en la sección de "Authorized redirect URIs":
    [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Luego de crear la credencial, nos va a salir una ventana con los valores de client secret y api key. Ignoramos eso. Y luego procedemos dar click en la flechita para descargar nuestro client secret.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Por último, guardamos este archivo json en la carpeta "gestor", dentro de nuestro directorio de trabajo; Es decir, donde están los otro archivos, y le ponemos el nombre de "**client_secret.json**":
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡ Listo ! Tenemos todo para hacer la prueba. Ahora simplemente ve a **http://localhost/gestor** y el resto sucederá por sí mismo. Los archivos con los que ya he probado son .pdf, .xlsx, pptx, .jpeg y .png.

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda como una guía y si te es útil esto, no olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: Te agradezco un montón el tiempo que te tomaste en armar una excelente respuesta, lo aprecio mucho, no obstante, tengo un problema. Uso un hosting compartido por lo que "servidor", "usuario" y "contraseña" sería "localhost" y usuario y password del cpanel o tengo que crear un usuario de base de datos ? La base de datos "gestor" no me la crea, y cuando intento manualmente me dice que ya existe, es raro.

Comment: No podría decirte cuales son las credenciales de tu hosting. Por eso el ejemplo lo hice usando un servidor local. Pero debería funcionar si estás poniendo las credenciales correctas. Si tu hosting usa phpMyAdmin, debería funcionar. Entrá a tu phpMyAdmin y mirá si no está creada la base de datos.

Comment: no está creada y cuando se intenta crear dice que ya existe, típicos errores de goddady, hace años estoy con ellos y te aseguro que es normal. En cambio, he creado la base de datos "db_gestor", cambié los valores en index.php y acceso.php. Actualmente me redirige a "gestor.html", pero no me deja descargar ni subir nada, aparecen desactivados los botones

Comment: Después de un rato logré quitar todo lo relacionado con BD e implementarlo en un json, ahora se guarda perfectamente el token y se redirecciona correctamente, no obstante, cuando me encuentro en /gestor/gestor.html todo aparece desactivado, es decir, no puedo ver, subir ni descargar, mirando en la consola esos 3 archivos fallan al hacer la petición ajax: GET mi.url.com/listar.php 500 (Internal Server Error), intenté cambiar los enlaces en scripts.js a los completos y el error persiste, no encuentro solución

Comment: Por favor, prueba intentar remover el accesso desde myaccount.google.com... luega borra las cookies e intenta nuevamente.

Comment: El error persiste. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Hola Morfinismo, después de todo el tiempo que te consumí ayer, ahora funciona casi perfecto, sólo queda pendiente una última cosa. La función refreshToken sigue fallado, por ende, el error 500 aparece luego de una hora de uso, esto se debe a que mi client_secret.json no tiene la clave "refresh_token" ¿qué debo hacer para que google me genere dicho archivo con esa clave/valor?

Comment: Tenés que quitar acceso de la app en myaccount.google.com, volver a autorizar para conseguir el token y no volver a reescribir el token después de eso.

Comment: Puedo hacer algo similiar pero en un script? lo que necesito es subir las copias de las base de datos de mi siervidor directamente a una cuenta google drive de forma automatizado sin interaccion del usuario.

Comment: @JulianProg Sí se puede.

Comment: Como podria hacerlo? estoy leyendo la documentacion de la Api de Google y decidi intentarlo con python, copie el codigo que ellos proporcionan como ejemplo y funciona, pero lo que hace es conectarse a google drive y mostrar los archivos. hay algun tutorial con el que pueda guiarme? instale la libreria de python pydrive que segun facilita las cosas pero me da un error y no he podida avanzar nada.

Comment: @JulianProg lo siento amigo. No tengo experiencia en Python. Si tenés experiencia con PHP, este tutorial te tiene que dar una idea de cómo hacerlo. Suerte!